# look for multiple column values in another data frame in spark/scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, lookup

I am having 2 data frames A & B.

A is having 30 columns- `reason1,reason2.......reason30`

B having 2 columns- `reason, Value`

Now I need to look for all the columns starting with reason* into B and fetch the corresponding value in one column in data frame A.

So, the Final data frame would have `reason1,reason2.......reason30, value`

I was trying to join each column with other data frame but that's not an neat approach.

Please help me to get an optimized and fast solution using spark/scala.

Comment: Welcome @Himanshu, please provide a minimal example of the input data you have, the output you expect and what you tried

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Array of columns of a dataframe using

```
df.columns
```

Then, you can iterate over the Array and check which column is present and prepare the join condition